# Sum and Group By issue

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I'm rather stumped here with an SQL statement between two tables, and a sum with group by clause.

Table 1:   num_calls_data

```
numcallsid, date_added,             date_of_call, teamlead, agent,    agent_username, agent_userrole, numcalls, teamsorter
'2275',     '2013-12-30 15:37:11', '2013-12-20', 'KARMEN', 'HANNAH', 'HannahCC',    'Front Office', '1',      '1'
'2276',     '2013-12-30 15:40:12', '2013-12-23', 'KARMEN', 'HANNAH', 'HannahCC', 'Support',      '1',      '2'
'2277',     '2013-12-30 15:40:48', '2013-12-23', 'KARMEN', 'HANNAH', 'HannahCC',    'Front Office', '0',      '1'
```

Table 2: dollars_data

```
dollarsid, date_added,            last_update_date, created_by, transaction_amt, enrollee, transaction_type, order_number, order_created
'21333',   '2013-12-30 15:38:39', '2013-12-20',     'HannahCC', '90.00',              '1',     'Item List Price', '345',        '2013-12-20'
'21334',   '2013-12-30 15:40:48', '2013-12-23',     'HannahCC', '-90.00',            '-1',    'Item Cancel',     '345',        '2013-12-20'
'21335',   '2013-12-30 15:40:48', '2013-12-23',     'HannahCC', '100.00',            '1',     'Item List Price', '999',        '2013-12-23'
```

SQL Statement:

```
SELECT  
t.agent_userrole as agent_userrole, 
t.teamlead as teamlead,
t.agent as agent, 
t.agent_username as agent_username, 
t.numcalls as numcalls, 
d.created_by as created_by, 
date_format(d.last_update_date,'%Y-%m-%e') as last_update_date, 
sum(d.transaction_amt) as transaction_amt, 
sum(d.enrollee) as enrollee,
t.teamsorter as teamsorter 
FROM callconversion.dollars_data d, callconversion.num_calls_data t  
WHERE
t.agent_username=d.created_by  
AND d.last_update_date between '2013-12-1' and '2013-12-29'  
AND t.date_of_call=d.last_update_date 
GROUP BY  last_update_date, teamsorter, teamlead, agent_userrole, agent  
ORDER BY teamsorter asc, teamlead asc, agent_userrole asc, agent asc, last_update_date asc
```

Returned output:

```
agent_userrole,          teamlead, agent,    agent_username, numcalls, created_by, last_update_date, transaction_amt, enrollee, teamsorter
'Front Office',         'KARMEN', 'HANNAH', 'HannahCC',     '1',      'HannahCC',  '2013-12-20',     '90.00',         '1',      '1'
'Front Office',         'KARMEN', 'HANNAH', 'HannahCC',     '0',      'HannahCC',  '2013-12-23',     **'10.00',        '0'**,   '1'
'Registration Support', 'KARMEN', 'HANNAH', 'HannahCC',     '1',      'HannahCC',  '2013-12-23',     **'10.00',        '0'**,   '2'
```

Expected/Desired output:

```
agent_userrole,          teamlead, agent,    agent_username, numcalls, created_by, last_update_date, transaction_amt, enrollee, teamsorter
'Front Office',          'KARMEN', 'HANNAH', 'HannahCC',     '1',      'HannahCC', '2013-12-20',     '90.00',         '1',      '1'
'Front Office',          'KARMEN', 'HANNAH', 'HannahCC',     '0',      'HannahCC', '2013-12-23',     **'-90.00',      '-1'**,   '1'
'Registration Support',  'KARMEN', 'HANNAH', 'HannahCC',     '1',      'HannahCC', '2013-12-23',     **'100.00',      '1'**,    '2'
```

It appears the `transaction_amt` and `enrollee` columns are getting summed up in a way I would not expect, based on the `GROUP BY` values. It appears to be summed up by the `last_update_date`, but not taking into account the `agent_userrole` column which has the differentiating factor.

Comment: First off I would recommend you update your join syntax to the ANSI 92 standard.  Instead of `FROM callconversion.dollars_data d, callconversion.num_calls_data t  WHERE t.agent_username = d.created_by` use `FROM callconversion.dollars_data d INNER JOIN callconversion.num_calls_data t ON t.agent_username=d.created_by`

Comment: Thanks Zane, will do.  I shouldn't expect a different result than I'm getting, but I'll update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `date_of_call` and `timestamp` seem to be dates only, not including the time. So each row in `dollars_data` that has `last_update_time = 2013-12-23` matches both rows in `num_calls_data` with `date_of_call = 2013-12-23`, so your output shows the sum of both rows. The 100.00 and -90.00, added together by the `sum()`, result in the 10.00 you get.

Comment: But shouldn't the inclusion of "agent_userrole" in the group by clause provide some differentiation to keep the sums on same days separate?

Comment: No, because it doesn't occur anywhere in the dollars_data table, and if it did, you'd have to use something like 't.agent_userrole=d.agent_userrole' as well. To check what happens, replace your `sum(x)` expressions with `x`, and omit the group by. You'll get 5 rows. These 5 rows get summed up after the initial select is done. (Ok, i'm oversimplifying here, the optimizer will handle it in a different way, but the result is the same).

Comment: Thanks Guntram, that makes sense.   Is there a way to achieve the desired results with the given data?  Or is that something I'd need to handle outside the SQL statement?

Comment: Check http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/625556/5 - use the mouse to select the upper statement, press the execute sql button, then think about what happens when you sum up all rows that have identical values in the `group by` columns. Your original statement is below as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you want, you have to create some sort of fake time/rank to differentiate the rows for the same Date so that it only joins once if it's on the same Day.
Here's an [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/142ec/18/0) that does something like that.

The only problem is that you don't know which agentuserroll will get assigned which amount because there seems to be nothing to keep track of this relationship within your tables.

Maybe you want to add the `order by` `numcallsid` and `dollarsid` to the inner queries so at least you know that a record that was created first will be joined with a record that was also created first (like this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/142ec/19/0))